# Как исключить страницы из условия, в котором заданы страницы?

Tags: php, wordpress

Допустим, имеется категория **Вода** (id='500') а в ней есть подразделы

1. Газировка
2. Сладкая
3. Соленая
4. Кислая
5. Невкусная

Я имею условие для всей категории и для ее внутренних страниц, чтобы одним махом отображать нужную информацию

```
 if ( is_page( 'Вода' ) || '1' == $post->post_parent) {
echo'что то'
}
```

Но иногда получается так, что нужно исключить некоторые страницы и не отображать показ информации.

Как исключить показ, например, для "кислая" и "Невкусная"

Пробовал сделать что-то подобное, но не вышло.

```
if ( is_page( 'Вода' ) || '500' == $post->post_parent) {
 if ( is_page(4) || is_page(5)) {
    echo'что то что не должно отображаться для этих двух категорий'
    }    

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понял вопрос, вам нужен такой код

```
if ( is_page( 'Вода' ) || 500 === $post->post_parent ) {
    if ( ! is_page( 4 ) && ! is_page( 5 ) ) {
        echo 'что-то, что не должно отображаться для этих двух категорий';
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы правильно поняли, но не хочет почему то работать

Comment: ` '500' === ` на  `'500' ==` и заработало

Comment: Поправил ответ. Если строгое сравнение `===`, то типы должны быть одинаковые. Вместо строки я сделал 500 числом (int).